# is it possible to customized Nutch Fetcher class?

Tags: java, solr, web-crawler, phantomjs, nutch

i am successful crawl web link and index data into solr.
but I need to create a pdf file for all link which will be crawl and index into Solr. 
I know phantoms will give me pdf but I didn't understand where I configure phantoms in Nutch.
I search about it and I know that I need to customize Fetcher class of Nutch, but I didn't know how to customize it. 
please any one can help. I am stuck on this from last two weeks.

Comment: Could you please clarify a little more, it is hard to understand what task are you trying to achieve here. Do you want a list of all urls that you have crawled up till now ?

Comment: @SujenShah i want create pdf for all url which will be crawl by nutch. so i need to know in which class i need to change so it will create pdf.(i am using phantomjs for creating pdf ).as i know only i need to put code in any class for creating pdf but till now i didn't find out class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into dumping the crawldb in a csv format ? I think you could achieve your task (which I understand is to get a list of all urls to be crawled by Nutch) without any code modification and following the below.

You could use `./bin/nutch readdb <crawldb path> -dump <output_dir> -format csv`

This command will give you all the urls fetched/unfetched in Nutch.
Once you have it in csv, you could easily export it as pdf.

For more info on the command have a look at https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20readdb

Comment: Actually my task is that i need to create pdf file for all URL which will be crawl by nutch and also when create pdf of URL i need to stored that PDF path into HBASE and that will be index into solr.